# Just want to send email from my Windows Server 2012, what simple SMTP server to use

Tags: windows-server-2012, smtp

I'm trying to configure SMTP on my window server 2012. I do the same as mention here (http://www.vsysad.com/2014/09/setup-and-configure-smtp-server-on-windows-server-2012/). I am trying to send test email through SMTP diagnostic tool i got the following eror:

Error: Expected "250" server rejected the recipiet address

What i'm missing ?